# mongoDB: document nesting vs separate collections vs hybrid approach

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I have a following structure: there are many `A`'s. Each `A` has an array of `B`'s, each `B` has an Array of `C`'s. All of them (`A`, `B`, `C`) should have following fields `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `name` and of course `id`.

This data will be presented in three tables.
First: name of A, count of B's inside of this A, count of C's inside all B's inside of this A, createdAt, updatedAt.

Second: name of B, name of it's parent A, count of C's inside this B, createdAt, updatedAt.

Third: name of C, name of it's parent B, name of this B's parent A, createdAt, updatedAt.

All those tables should have filtering, pagination, sorting.

I thought that I'd like to have as little collections count as possible, so I went with nesting, however it's been a nightmare. All this unwinding, faceting, projecting seems so complicated. Currently I'm struggling with filtering eg. I want in third table to get all C's that are in particular B and it's driving me nuts.

So the question is more about the structure. Is this a right structure or should I go with separate collections for A, B and C's or maybe the hybrid approach so all in one collection, but with Id's reffering to the parent element as well as type field A/B/C. I want the queries to be the as simple as possible. Each A, B, C can of course be updated, deleted.
Users should also be able to add new A, B and C's.